# Need help looping JSON with JavaScript. Weird behaviours

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Although, it ran fine on small data. I need help looping through JSON in this form:

```
var current_value = 2;
json_data = {"2":"first information","3":"Second informaton","4":"Third information"}
```

What I want to do is get the value in the json_data that corresponds to current_value of 2
The problem is that I keep getting **"** anytime I run this loop:

```
for(x in json_data){
    if(x === current_value){
        extracted = json_data[current_value];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not actually Json you have there, it's an object literal.

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @Keith unless it is actually a JSON string and they're not parsing it, may be why they are getting `"`

Comment: You loop through all keys, and if the current key equals a predetermined value, you take the predetermined value out of the object… The entire loop is superfluous for doing that.

Comment: @George — If that is the case, then their code example does not represent their real code.

Comment: @George , like Quentin said, I deduced it's not a JSON string, by the second line of his first code snippet..

Comment: I'm not really understanding what your asking for here, but I think it's worth noting that there's no reason to run a loop just to grab a value. Simply writing `extracted = json_data[value]` will give the same result as the entire loop here, and if you do need to loop then `Object.keys(json_data).forEach(/*...*/)` or `map` will give you much nicer, more declarative syntax.

Comment: Thanks @George. I didn't parse it. After parsing it, I then typecasted the  current_value into string. I have been able to solve the problem. Thanks for these tips.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin for that article

Comment: @franc,  what do you mean parse it?, there is nothing to parse in the code you supplied.  Did you have this by any chance -> `json_data = '{"2":"first information","3":"Second informaton","4":"Third information"}'`, you spot the extra `'`..

Comment: @Keith Yes.. the data is coming from a remote database. So I used JSON.encode()..on arriving at the client side, I didn't use JSON.parse(json_data). Without doing JSON.parse(json_data), I will still get the same error. And no, I didn't have that by any chance. It is in fact JSON but I didn't parse it so I kept getting wrong results until I parsed it.

Comment: @franc , in the future could you post your actual code used, the first snippet is totally valid Javascript, and by posting it like this has just caused confusion.  If your getting the result viaAjax then you should have posted that.

Comment: @Keith will bear that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript property names are *strings*. `2` is a *number*. `===` does not do type conversion. `"2" !== 2`.

You should set `current_value` to `"2"` instead of `2`.

---

The loop is pointless though.

A more sensible approach would be:

```
var extracted;
if (current_value in json_data) { 
    extracted = json_data[current_value];
}
```

… or even just skip the `if` statement. `extracted` will be `undefined` either way if the property doesn't exist.